# How do I unlock more layouts?

Tags: animal-crossing-happy-home-designer

I completed the handbook which unlocked the ability to use layouts, but so far I just have a few options: a small 4x4 side room on any side, a wide layout, a tall layout, a slightly bigger square layout and the normal one.

I had heard that there are people using multiple more complex layouts but I'm not sure if these are unlocked later (according to the game I'm done with the handbook and I seem to have stopped unlocking major features) or if certain buildings/requests just have more layout options than normal houses.